# Android Video Encryption and playback

Tags: android, video, encryption, playback

I am building a app form where users can download a video but can not play using inbuild video player. 
Only from within the app user can play it.

I tried the following:

1. Downloaded the video using android downloadManager to download folder.
2. then I am encrypting the video using android cipher and algo AES.
3. then I am deleting the origin downloaded video.
4. I have implemented `videoview`,to play video.
5. from app I am de-cipering the video and then plugging it into video view source.

but it's not working.
All my videos are in .mp4 format.

Here is the code for ciphering and de-cyphering video(taken on another stackover answer, but don't have link anymore)

```
try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME))));
    File outfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/appvideo/1.mp4");

    int read;
    if(!outfile.exists())
        outfile.createNewFile();

    File decfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/appvideo/2.mp4");
    if(!decfile.exists())
        decfile.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    FileInputStream encfis = new FileInputStream(outfile);
    FileOutputStream decfos = new FileOutputStream(decfile);

    Cipher encipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    encipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, encipher);
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(decfos,decipher);

    while((read = cis.read())!=-1)
    {
        fos.write((char)read);
        fos.flush();
    }
    fos.close();
    while((read=encfis.read())!=-1)
    {
        cos.write(read);
        cos.flush();
    }
    cos.close();

}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exceptione
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and my videoplay back code is

```
try {
    //set the media controller in the VideoView
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
    mediaControls.setAnchorView(videoView);
    //set the uri of the video to be played
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/appvVideo/3.mp4")));

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong.

what is good way for
download and encrypt the video and later decrypt form app that can be play only with app?

Comment: I am too trying to do the same thing . U got any solutions ?